# Yii how to render index instead of application.modules.modulename.views.modulename.index

Tags: yii

How to make

```
$this->render('index');
```

instead of

```
$this->render('application.modules.modulename.views.modulename.index');
```

in a module's controller? Tried googling and

```
$this->setbasePath('application.modules.modulename')
```

in ModulenameModule but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: that should be enabled by default. have you generated your module with gii?

Comment: Yes, it is generated with gii.

Comment: so i guess if you use render('index'), you get `cannot find the requested view "index"` error? have you checked modules basePath with getBasePath() ? incase you don't know you can do `$this->module->getBasePath();` in your view, to confirm

Comment: I added echo $this->getBasePath() in ModulenameController's function index. Got an error saying ModulenameController and its behavior do not have a method or closure named "getBasePath". I make ModulenameController extends CController. It was extends Controller.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just checked the Class Reference, changed it into echo $this->getViewPath(); The result is C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\protected\views\modulename. Sorry, I'm newbie to Yii.

Comment: well it should be C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\protected\modules\modulename\views\controllername

Comment: @TendouKishi, do your module controller placed in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\protected\modules\modulename\controllers\ ? And in config ['modules'][] = 'modulename' ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this->render('application.modules.modulename.views.modulename.index');
```

you can use

```
$this->render('/index');
```

The main application view root is referenced with `//` and within the module with a single slash `/`.